# how do I split with preg_split in php my lines?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have following text

```
        <h2>Subjects</h2>
        <ul>

        <li><a href='http://isbndb.com/subject/transfer_pricing'>
        Transfer pricing</a></li>

        <li><a   
        hef='http://isbndb.com/subject/intangible_property_valuation'>   
        Intangible property -- Valuation</a></li>


        </ul>
```

the numbers of `<li> .. </li>` could be variable.
Can anyone tell me the regex to get

```
     Transfer pricing
     Intangible property -- Valuation
```

it might be done with preg_split, but I have no glue how the regex should be.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you shouldn't use regex to parse html, you will have alot of challenges with it. Consider using `\DomDocument` instead

Comment: @Augwa Do you h ave more infos about this?

Comment: Here is the question that will answer it all for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Thanks a lot! Congratulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this:

```
   $output = "<h2>Subjects</h2>
    <ul>

    <li><a href='http://isbndb.com/subject/transfer_pricing'>
    Transfer pricing</a></li>

    <li><a   
    hef='http://isbndb.com/subject/intangible_property_valuation'>   
    Intangible property -- Valuation</a></li>


    </ul>";

   preg_match_all("li><a href='(.[^>]*)>(.[^<]*)</",$output , $array_check);


        print_r($array_check);
```